# How can I inject HTML from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using angular I can use `ng-include` to inject a piece of html from server into current position of the DOM.

Is there a pure JavaScript library that would simulate the same thing?

I need this because I have a simple html page with a lot of `~modal dialogs~`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deposit-pm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

which I'd like to extract into a separate .html files.

Can I do this using jQuery only?

Comment: You can use $.load() to load external html files. check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **[jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

```
$("#divId").load("htmlurl.com/file.html")
```

This will load the html content in that particular DOM with id "divId"